# Performance difference when using find+projection vs select

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Is there a difference or performance penalty when I use `db.collection.find('stuff'{projection})` vs `db.collection.find('stuff').select({'keyWeWant'})`?
I've struggled with documentation for a while now and can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to check $explain, you will find the actual query execution. I believe internally it will same

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/explain/

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain which language you are using because the syntax

```
db.collection.find('stuff').select({'keyWeWant'})
```

Is something I don't know.

For your question :
Using projection wil only return the fields included in the projection so you will save network. You can utilize this even further and create a so called covered-index, that holds the query keys and projection keys and so you get your data directly from the index which will be a serious performance gain.
Offcourse, adding to much data to your index will hurt the performance on that side so choose your battle wisely

Regards
Chris